# Printing out elements of dynamic array or matrix

Tags: c++

Why does this simple code for printing out an array not work?

```
void main()
{

    cout<<"Simple for\n";
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the lenght of array:";
    cin>>n;
    int* a= new int[n];
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        a[j]=0;
        cout<<setw(8)<<a[j];
        //getchar();

    }
    getchar();  
    delete[]a;


}
```

The output disappears quickly.

When n is constant its works but when n comes  from input it doesn't work.
When getchar put in the For, it only prints out two elements of the array with any length.

What is wrong?

Comment: What is the problem at all? Are you receiving an error?

Comment: No error. it only print tow elements instead of printing all off them.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want this:

```
int* a= new int[n];
```

C++ is not C; you don't allocate "bytes" with `new`; you allocate objects. Arrays, types, etc. So if you want an array of `n` values of type `int`, then you allocate that. No need for `sizeof`, multiplication, etc.

Note that anything you allocate with the array version of `new` (ie: `new Type[]`) must be deleted with the array version of delete:

```
delete []a;
```

The size is unnecessary; you just need to make sure that `new[]` is paired with `delete[]`

Comment: Also worthwhile to mention to delete with `delete []`

Comment: Ok but my problem isn,t it.the problem is  printing only two element for all value for n.

Answer (score 2):

This allocation

```
int* a= new int(n*sizeof(int));
```

only allocates a single `int` and sets its initial value to `n*sizeof(int)`. Not exactly what you wanted.

The correct way to allocate n ints is

```
int* a = new int[n];
```

or even better

```
std::vector<int>   a(n);
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified it.But it still print out two elements.

Comment: It works for me here http://ideone.com/IdkuY and prints 5 elements (all zero) if I enter 5.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone
The problem is solved..
But I don,t know why.
Can anyone explain the role of another getchar() here?

---

This is new code:

```
int main()
{
cout<<"Simple for\n";
int n;
cout<<"Enter the lenght of array:";
cin>>n;
int* a= new int[n];
for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        a[j]=0;
        cout<<setw(8)<<a[j];
                  }
    delete[]a;
    getchar();  
    getchar();
}
```